# Вопрос по ошибке при запуске скрипта

Tags: perl

Скрипт выдает ошибку, в чем может быть проблема?

> sudo /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh
>   /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.conf
>
> Can't locate Data/UUID.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /home/projects/SHARED_API /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2
>   /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5
>   /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at
>   /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 10. BEGIN failed--compilation
>   aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 10. Compilation failed
>   in require at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12. BEGIN
>   failed--compilation aborted at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line
>   12. Compilation failed in require at /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh line 75.
>   BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
>   /home/projects/system_sms_partition/delete_old_partitions.sh line 75.

Comment: Выдается ниже описанная ошибка, правильно ли, что нужно ставить модули по отдельности
Can't locate Sub/Install.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/projects/SHARED_API /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 11.

Answer (score 2):

Perl не может найти модуль `Data/UUID.pm`

Comment: Сложно назвать ответом. Добавили бы в него информацию об установке Data::UUID с помощью cpan, например

Comment: Вопрос был "в чем может быть ошибка?"

Comment: Написать пару строк об установке - не проблема, а начинающим, которые еще сами не понимают таких ошибок очень полезно

Comment: Спасибо установил, теперь видимо нехватает еще одного модуля: Can't locate Sub/Install.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/projects/SHARED_API /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/Data/GUID.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/projects/SHARED_API/db.pm line 12.